# Net Framework 4 or 3.5 for new application C# WPF

Tags: .net

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww.aspx

Based on the above link what should i chose ? I am forced to stick to .Net 3.5 because it has  less hardware requirements.. However on my XP 2gb ram machine it takes 30 s to load a .net 3.5 program..,so i think that it would take hours to run a simple .net program at machine with less than 512 mb ram !! so there is no reason to stick to 3.5.. 
But it takes too much disk space!! WTF 1.5 GB for .net 4 ??? it is too much..
What should i choose for better compatibility ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are your application will be able to target the .NET 4.0 Client Profile. Disk Space requirement is 600MB, however the download size for your users (IIRC) is around 40MB.

I see no reason to use 3.5 over 4.0, the benefits definitely outweigh the negatives you could find about it.

Comment: It means that on old systems 20gb hard disk it would take 600 mb ? I know the negatives :( WPF in 3.5 is not so good as 4. I had many problems before.. but i need reasons to support that because i amnot the project leader-manager.The problem IS that old computers and .net cant go together but IT MUST be done in NET and WPF.. thats the problem..

Comment: To be honest, I've never trusted these "requirements". The only way to find out exactly what it will use is to install it, checking disk space before and after.